# SSRS 2008 R2 Tablix Goto URL Action Outlook

Tags: url, reporting-services, outlook, action, ssrs-2008-r2

Reporting Services 2008 R2 Tablix Go to URL Action . . . I have the following expression . . .

="mailto:" & "email" & "?subject=" & "My Email Subject" & Fields!ReferenceNo.Value & "-" & Fields!ShortName.Value & "&body=" & "Hi," + vbcrlf + vbcrlf + "My Body Message" & Fields!ReferenceNo.Value & " - " & Fields!ShortName.Value & " " & "needs commentary." & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "I'll be checking this later!" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & System.Uri.EscapeDataString(""

which displays and opens an email message fine . . . however . . . replacing the "email" with Fields!Name.Value seems to make the action stop working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer to this is to start the expression as

="mailto://" &  . . .